# How to find the size of the largest file in a directory?

Tags: java

I need to find out the size of the largest file/folder in a directory. I have done it in the below way.

```
private static Long getSizeofLargestFile(String theRootFolder)
    {
        Long aLargestFileSize = 0L;
        File aRootDir = new File(theRootFolder);
        for (File aFile : aRootDir.listFiles())
        {
            if (aLargestFileSize < aFile.length())
            {
                aLargestFileSize = aFile.length();
            }
        }
        return aLargestFileSize / (1024 * 1024);
    }
```

*Can there be a better way than this?*

Comment: I think you should go with `return aLargestFileSize;`

Comment: What happens to sub directories?

Comment: The code looks good and clean (except formatting). Why are you looking for something else. Do you see any performance issue with this code?

Comment: You might get a tiny bit more efficiency by using primitive `long` instead of the wrapper type `Long` (to avoid all the boxing and unboxing) but apart from that it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 6):

Not really.. You have to get the sizes of all files to find the largest, which is what you are doing.

The only thing I would advise against is the division in the return. If the largest file is less than one MB, then your method will return 0!

Answer (score 4):

I would say instead of

```
return aLargestFileSize / (1024 * 1024);
```

go with

```
return aLargestFileSize;
```

I will write why in some time...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Long aLargestFileSize1 = (1024*1024)+2 + 0L;
        Long aLargestFileSize2 = (1024*1024)+ 0L;

        System.out.println("aLargestFileSize1 final is " + aLargestFileSize1/ (1024 * 1024));
        System.out.println("aLargestFileSize2 final is " + aLargestFileSize2/ (1024 * 1024));

        System.out.println("aLargestFileSize1 new is " + aLargestFileSize1);
        System.out.println("aLargestFileSize2 new is " + aLargestFileSize2);

        }
}
```

If you see output both are giving 1. But if you would had `System.out.println("aLargestFileSize1 final is " + aLargestFileSize1);`, then output would have been,

```
aLargestFileSize1 new is 1048578
aLargestFileSize2 new is 1048576
```

means first file is larger.

So, just use actual number in return.

### [Demo](http://ideone.com/VPZpCF)

Answer (score 2):

I see a whole bunch of issues:

- First the division has rounding issues (see other answers for that)
- Should an empty root directory really return `0`? Consider `-1`.
- If there is only directories in the the root directory should that return `0` or `-1` (see next point)
- Do you want to recurse on directories for size or do you want to exclude them.
- I recommend you return the largest `File` instead of the size to remove ambiguity.

If your not adverse to using external libraries Commons IO has a plethora of *correct* ways to do what you want using its [SizeFileComparator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/comparator/package-summary.html) and friends.

The other reason you might want to use Commons IO (besides making mistakes like the `1024 * 1024` rounding problem) is that I believe the latest will take advantage of newer JVM features and it also provides recursive directory size (ie the largest file could be another directory).

If you don't want to use the library I recommend at the bare minimum looking at its [code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/) to figure out how to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 offers the new java.nio.* classes including a FileVisitor:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

I used them already, but i cant say, which solution is the better one. 
In my opinion you should keep your solution, because it is better to read.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me, with a couple of possible improvements.

First, it looks like you're not interested in exploring sub-directories. If that's really the case, I'd pass a `FileFilter` to `listFiles` - that'll allow you to easily filter out all instances whose `isFile()` method returns `false`.

Second, I'd not divide the return value by 1024 * 1024. Return the number of bytes, and let the caller make the conversion himself. The reason for that is that if no file is bigger than 1024 * 1024 byte, your method will return 0l.